# HTML <select> element is abbreviated in iPhone or Android browsers

Tags: iphone, jquery, android, html, jquery-ui

I'm in a bit of a situation with my HTML **<select>** dropdowns, when they are displayed in an iPhone or Android browser. I often need to render **<option>** labels that are quite long, such as for instance

> [AccountType] [EUR] - [Customer] - CH12 3456 7890 1234 5678 9

On Android, this will render something like that:

> [image: android screen]

On the iPhone it's even worse. While I like the native look and feel, the cropping of the labels is a no-go. Circled in red, you'll find how the dropdown itself is rendered. I could live with that. But check out the blue popup that appears, when I click on it. The user will never find his data...

### PLEASE, before you answer...

... consider these points:

- I can abbreviate some information, but I will still have cases with long option labels in the select. So no need to tell me that the IBAN could be abbreviated, etc.
- I cannot rely on CSS styling of **<select>** or **<option>** elements.
- User hunter has already proposed the **<optgroup>** tag [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4554831/html-select-element-is-abbreviated-too-much-in-iphone-or-android-browsers#4554858). That's quite a nice idea and will be a small workaround, but is not enough, as the IBAN is still cropped by both iPhone and Android browsers :-(
- I already know the very nice looking [jQuery UI Selectmenu prototype](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/). Unfortunately, it's not yet compatible with jquery-ui 1.8.5 and there is no guarantee when it will be stable.
- I am using jquery and jquery-ui 1.8.5, so any ideas / references to plugins are very welcome.
- Any other ideas to circumvent that problem **GENERALLY** are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the proposed workarounds given by *hunter* and *Ivan Buttinoni* were creative, and good ideas, I had to find a different solution in the end. It now looks similar to jQuery UI's combobox component:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox

Answer (score 5):

Are you able to create groups of `option`s to minimize the redundant text?

```
<option value="-1">[AccountType] [EUR] - [Customer]</option>
<option value="1">CH12 3456 7890 1234 5678 9</option>
<option value="2">CH10 1111 2222 3333 4444 5</option>
```

Then make the `value="-1"` unselectable with jQuery

or you could use `optgroup` elements for organization

```
<optgroup label="[AccountType] [EUR] - [Customer]">
    <option value="1">CH12 3456 7890 1234 5678 9</option>
    <option value="2">CH10 1111 2222 3333 4444 5</option>
</optgroup>
```

Comment: That's a nice idea, actually. I hadn't thought of that. Maybe even using the **<optgroup>** tag... The IBAN is still going to be too large for the iPhone, though :-/

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the `font-size` css of the select box?

Comment: Unfortunately, changing the font-size is not possible. The **<optgroup>** tag is a small improvement. Not enough though. As I expected, the IBAN is still too long for both Android and iPhone browsers

Comment: I would snoop around apple.com and see what options you have for styling their select elements but I'm guessing you either change the font size for mobile browsers or create your own means of selecting things using a `<ul>` with some custom js

Comment: I'll go with your solution. `<optgroup label="[Customer]"><option>[AccountType]</option></optgroup>` is good enough. I can't think of anything else...

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem. I wanted an imitation drop-down box similar to the jQuery UI combobox but I didn't want to use jQuery UI so I used this other [jQuery selectbox plugin](http://www.bulgaria-web-developers.com/projects/javascript/selectbox/). It is somewhat buggy but better for my purposes than the default iPhone select element.

Comment: Looks nice. How does the "overflow" scrollbar work on the iPhone? I found this to be a problem for most mobile devices.

Comment: It doesn't work. If there are too many choices to fit, you can't scroll. I tried to make it scrollable using iScroll, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I try to solve the problem with a different approach, moving out the "long data" from select block into an another kind of form more easy to manage.
 
Here's a draft of my idea:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.clickme{
        text-decoration: underline;
        color: blue;
}
</style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var iban=[
                [{"idx":"11","iban":"CH12 3456 7890 1234 5678 9"},{"idx":"12","iban":"CH12 3333 3333 3333 3333 9"}],
                [{"idx":"13","iban":"CH99 3333 3333 3333 3333 9"}],
                [{"idx":"14","iban":"CH88 3333 3333 3333 3333 9"},{"idx":"15","iban":"CH77 3333 3333 3333 3333 9"}]
                ];


$().ready(function(){

                $(".select_show").change(function(){
                        var testo="";
                        for( var t in iban[ $(this).val() ]){
                                if(testo==""){
                                        testo="Please select one following iban<br/>";
                                }
                                testo=testo + "<div class='clickme' value='"+ iban[ $(this).val() ][t].idx +"'>"+ iban[ $(this).val() ][t].iban +"</div><br/>";
                        }
                        $("#choices").html(testo);

                        $(".clickme").click(function(){
                                $("#hidden1").val($(this).attr('value'));
                                $("#choices").html("thanks");
                        });

                });

});
    </script>

</head>
<body >

<form>
<input type="text" id="hidden1" name="real_select_input" value=""> <br/>
<select class="select_show" id="select1">
        <option selected="selected" value="-1">please select</option>
        <option value="0">[AccountType] [EUR] - [Customer1]</option>
        <option value="1">[AccountType] [EUR] - [Customer2]</option>
        <option value="2">[AccountType] [EUR] - [Customer3]</option>
</select>
</form>
<div id="choices">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Iban is an array of array:
the first level contain your different accounts
the second one the different profile for each customer.

the "hidden1" is suppose to be hidden :)

PS
I was missed the comment of hunter on "Dec 29 '10 at 14:42" pointing this way

Comment: thanks for your effort! That looks promising. I will try this ASAP

Comment: Hmm, I understand now, you're kind of emulating a second select by generating links... That will be a bit too verbose on a mobile screen. But your hint gave me a new idea. I may just try to put the [AccountType] in the select (that's short enough) and then dynamically display all the additional information below, just as info...

Comment: It's a good suggestion, but it's using too much space, again... Damn that lack of space on mobile devices :-)